# Delete duplicate string in array

Tags: php, arrays

In fact im working in a small php script , I'm using simple html dom to get some tags for a website, any way this is the code that i'm using

```
 if( strpos($a, '#') !== false ) 
{
    if( strpos($a, 'page') !== false ){}
        else
        {
            if( strpos($a, '#') !== false ){}
                else{
                    $items[] = $a;
                }
        }
}
```

I want to delete duplicate string in the array `$items`.

Comment: And where are you running into trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just check to see if the string has already been added?

```
if( strpos($a, '#') !== false ) 
{
    if( strpos($a, 'page') !== false ){}
        else
        {
            if( strpos($a, '#') !== false ){}
                else{
                    if(!in_array($a, $items)){
                        $items[] = $a;
                    }
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is from a comment of php.net (https://www.php.net/function.array-unique)

```
<?php
    $input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
    $result = array_unique($input);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Output:
Array
(
[a] => green
[0] => red
[1] => blue
)

Thanks Mark!

Comment: Yeah Mark that's a better approach-  See changes above

Answer (score 0):

If you can't check for already added items for some reason (as previously suggested) you could take a look at the [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) method.

/edit: 
This is unrelated to the question, but just in case that the snippet you posted is your actual code: you should really not use `if( strpos($a, 'page') !== false ){} else ...`

Just invert the condition and place the code in the `if` block:

```
if (strpos($a, 'page') === false) {
    // your code here
}
```